# libdouble-conversion1:amd64: libdouble-conversion1v5:amd64 conflicts

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation

In attempting to install Cisco's packet tracer, I am getting a conflict with `libdouble-conversion1`. Has anyone any idea about how to solve this?

My OS is ubuntu 16.04, 64 bit.

```
sudo dpkg -i libdouble-conversion1_3.1.0-3_amd64.deb

dpkg: regarding libdouble-conversion1_3.1.0-3_amd64.deb containing libdouble-conversion1:amd64:
      libdouble-conversion1v5:amd64 conflicts with libdouble-conversion1
      libdouble-conversion1:amd64 (version 3.1.0-3) is to be installed.
 
dpkg: error processing archive libdouble-conversion1_3.1.0-3_amd64.deb (--install):
  conflicting packages - not installing libdouble-conversion1:amd64
Errors were encountered while processing: 
  libdouble-conversion1_3.1.0-3_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Are you sure the packet tracer explicitly needs `libdouble-conversion1`? Have you tried it with your existing `libdouble-conversion1v5`?

Comment: Well I tried to install the deb file and it says - dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of packettracer:
 packettracer depends on libdouble-conversion1; however:
  Package libdouble-conversion1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package packettracer (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

Comment: Ah, right. Did you get the .deb directly from Cisco?

Comment: Yes downloaded from netacad.com.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by downloading an earlier version from Cisco of the Packet Tracer.